# Can io.Reader accept a file descriptor? "Unexpected end of JSON Input"

Tags: go

`json.Unmarshal` of valid JSON fails, after passing open file descriptor from os.Create() to a function the accepts type io.Reader and running io.Copy(b.Bytes(), reader)

Is the `Read()` method in the below code blocks being implemented correctly? `io.Reader` wraps the `Read` method, but will passing an open file descriptor to it *read* the file in to bytes, allowing io.Copy(b.Bytes(), reader) to copy the data into var b?

Is there a better way to do this without using `ioutil.ReadAll`?

1. Verified that the JSON is fully valid. Validated with jq and 3 online JSON validators.
2. Verified that data is actually being written to the file successfully through another function that implements io.Write.
3. Verified that `ioutil.ReadAll` can read the JSON in to bytes, so I think the method being used is implemented incorrectly.

** This isn't my code, I'm troubleshooting code written by someone else, who is unavailable for any questions **

I have a json file `collected_data.json`.

The file is created with os.Create

```golang
file, err := os.Create("/var/log/collected_data.json")
```

A struct is configured, which sets `file` to `DataStore`:

```golang
profiler := &collectors.SystemProfiler{
  DataStore:         file,
  NetworkInterfaces: interfaces,
  ApiURL:            *apiURL,
  RunOnce:           *runOnce,
  SysTag:            *sysTag,
}
```

We then run a `Gather()` method.

```golang
err = profiler.Send(output)
if err != nil {
  log.Error(err)
}
```

The `Send()` method implements the SystemProfiler struct:

```golang
func (s *SystemProfiler) Send(profile *SystemProfile) error {...}
```

Everything works fine getting to this point, up until a section of code where we try to read and unmarshall data from `/var/log/collected_data.json`.

Inside this `Send()` method, we try to read the file `/var/log/collected_data.json` in 2 scenarios.

1st, if the file is not empty, we read the file, and do something with it (not shown here).

```golang
data, err := store.Read(s.DataStore)
if err != nil {
  log.Print("I couldn't read the datastore")
  return err
}
```

2nd, if the file *isn't* empty, we write data to the file, and then immediately read it back in and Unmarshal to satisfy a later function that does a `reflect.DeepEqual` between data compared and data written to the file.

In both cases, the `Read()` method returns "Unexpected end of JSON input", with valid JSON in the file `/var/log/collected_data.json`. The method being used to write data works just fine.

```
{"level":"info","msg":"I couldn't read the datastore","time":"2019-08-02T02:26:42-04:00"}
{"level":"error","msg":"unexpected end of JSON input","time":"2019-08-02T02:26:42-04:00"}
```

The `Read()` method looks like this:

```golang
// Read reads JSON data from an io.Reader
func Read(reader io.Reader) (interface{}, error) {
  var data interface{}
  var b bytes.Buffer
  io.Copy(&b, reader)

  err := json.Unmarshal(b.Bytes(), &data)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }
  return data, nil
}
```

Expected results:

Valid JSON is copied from reader of type io.Reader to b of type bytes.Buffer, successfully unmarshalled, and returned.

Actual result:
{"level":"error","msg":"unexpected end of JSON input","time":"2019-08-02T02:26:42-04:00"}

To answer a question asked in the comments, here is the block of code inside the `Send()` function:

```golang
var storedProfile SystemProfile

    check := store.IsEmpty(s.DataStore)

    if check == false {
        log.Print("Data Store Exists") 
        // If there is data stored, read it
        data, err := store.Read(s.DataStore)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        //var tmp SystemProfile
        err = mapstructure.Decode(data, &storedProfile)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    } else {
        log.Print("Data Store Doesn't Exist")
        // If the data store is empty, write to it
        err := store.Write(s.DataStore, profile)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        data, err := store.Read(s.DataStore)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("I couldn't read the datastore")
            return err
        }
        err = mapstructure.Decode(data, &storedProfile)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("I couldn't decode the json to a map")
            return err
        }

        body, err := json.Marshal(profile)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        _, err = client.Post(s.ApiURL, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(body)) // TODO: Handle response from API here
        log.Print(client.LogString())
    }

if !reflect.DeepEqual(storedProfile, profile ) {
        // If what's in the data store and what has been collected are different,
        // write the recently collected data to the data store and send it out to the API
        store.Write(s.DataStore, profile)
        body, err := json.Marshal(profile)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        _, err = client.Post(s.ApiURL, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(body)) // TODO: Handle response from API here
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        log.Print(client.LogString())
    }
```

Comment: `io.Reader` doesn't "accept" anything and it doesn't "wrap" any methods. It is an interface, one that `*os.File` satisfies.

Comment: Is the application reading and writing the JSON from the same *os.File?  If so, does the application seek back to beginning of the file after writing and before reading the JSON?

Comment: @Adrian, was just referencing what I read in the godocs:
https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader
```Reader is the interface that wraps the basic Read method.```

Either way, is the implementation here incorrect? I'm banging my head against the wall on this.

Comment: @CeriseLimón not that I can tell. This application is an agent that collects data from the filesystem, and writes to the mentioned file as JSON. On the next run, if the data  collected != the data stored in the file (uses reflect.DeepEqual), it will post the data to an API. 

The way the Send() method is set up, it always tries to do a reflect between data collected and data stored, so my quick fix is if the data store doesn't have data, write to it, send to the API the first time, and try to read it back in so that the reflect doesn't eval as false and re-post the data to the API again.

Comment: @AustinH In your quick fix, do you use the same *os.File for write and read?  In your quick fix, do you seek back to beginning of the file between write and read?  Post the code for your quick fix.

Comment: @CeriseLimón sure, let me update the post.

Comment: After writing the data, the file position is at the end of the file.  Immediate read on the file will return EOF.  Seek back to the beginning of the file before reading.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thank you. Thats what I'm gathering from the docs, it just doesn't appear to be working... Is there a case then where `json.Unmarshal` would fail to unmarshal what is by all other accounts/tests fully valid JSON, and fails? Even with fully validated JSON?

Comment: @CeriseLimón OH... I did not know that... Let me try that. Not sure how to seek back at to the beginning, but I'll look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is yes. An `*os.File` can be used as an `io.Reader`.

The problem is that the application writes data to the file and then attempts to read that same data from the file without seeking back where the data was written.

Fix the problem by adding the following code after the call to store.Write and before the call to store.Read.

```
 if _, err := s.DataStore.Seek(io.SeekStart, 0); err != nil {
     return err
 }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm! I didn't know you had to seek to the start again.. Literally nowhere else I looked mentioned that. Thank you so much!

Comment: File descriptors have a current position.  Reads and writes start at the current position and advance the position.  There are many questions on SO that cover this concept.